# how to set permanent default timezone in mysql server

Tags: mysql

I am using **default_time_zone='+00:00'** in my.conf file and restart mysql server. But again default time zone is showing SYSTEM.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-timezone-of-mysql

Comment: Thanks.But this link is not clear solution. anyway I have got the solution - Go to /etc/mysql/my.conf and in Mysqld tag put the code default_time_zone='+00:00'

Answer (score 21):

In `my.conf` file, try:

```sql
[mysqld]
...
# default_time_zone='+00:00'
default-time-zone=+00:00
...
```

Documentation: [5.1.3. Server Command Options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html): [--default-time-zone=timezone](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_default-time-zone)

Comment: Yes this is correct. and add this line default-time-zone=+00:00 under [mysqld] section then it will work.

Comment: Is it possible to use timezones instead of time offsets? Like `AEDT` or `Australia/Sydney`?

Comment: @kev: See [10.6 MySQL Server Time Zone Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html).

Comment: I read it, doesn't help, hence I asked here (where you commented already): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688434/where-to-set-time-zone-in-mysql-5-7-config-files. It doesn't mention sections at all and doesn't explain the error messages I am getting.

Comment: @kev Named time zones can be used only if the time zone information tables in the mysql database have been created and populated. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html#time-zone-installation

Answer (score 7):

I use Ubuntu so on my machine location of the config file is:

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

add the value:

```
default_time_zone='+00:00'
```

Comment: Hello, afterwards, I also had to do: "sudo service mysql restart" for the update to take effect. Hope this helps. Thank you! Peace.